# VHDL object is used but not declared.

Tags: vhdl

I am working on project for school for a 10-4 encoder with two outputs.  I am pretty confident in the architecture, I think my error is just syntax.  I keep getting that "object T1 is used by not declared"  please any help would be amazing!  Our instruction was to find the first MSB then mask it and find the second one.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity enhanced_prio is 
    port(
        r: in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0); 
        fst, snd: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) 
        ); 
end enhanced_prio; 


architecture count of enhanced_prio is 

 signal temp:std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
 signal t1:std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

process (temp,t1)
begin

if(r="1000000000")then 
    fst <= "1010";
    t1  <= "1010";

    else (r = "0100000000") then 
   fst <= "1001";
    t1 <= "1001";

    elsif (r = "0010000000") then
   fst <= "1000";
    t1 <= "1000";

    elsif (r = "0001000000") then 
    fst <= "0111";
    t1 <= "0111";

    elsif (r = "0000100000") then
    fst <= "0110";
    t1 <= "0110";

    elsif (r = "0000010000") then
    fst <= "0101";
    t1 <= "0101";

    elsif (r = "0000001000") then
    fst <= "0100";
    t1 <= "0100";

    elsif (r = "0000000100") then
    fst <= "0011";
    t1 <= "0011";

    elsif (r = "0000000010") then
    fst <= "0010";
    t1 <= "0010";

    elsif (r = "0000000001") then   
    fst <= "0001";
    t1 <= "0001";

    else (r = other ) then
    fst<= "1111";
    t1 <= "1111";
    end if; 

if (t1 = "1010") then temp <= r AND "0111111111";
elsif (t1 = "1001") then temp <= r AND "0011111111";    
elsif (t1 = "1000") then temp <= r AND "0001111111";
elsif (t1 = "0111") then temp <= r AND "0000111111";
elsif (t1 = "0110") then temp <= r AND "0000011111";
elsif (t1 = "0101") then temp <= r AND "0000001111";
elsif (t1 = "0100") then temp <= r AND "0000000111";
elsif (t1 = "0011") then temp <= r AND "0000000011";
elsif (t1 = "0010") then temp <= r AND "0000000001";
elsif (t1 = "0001") then temp <= r AND "0000000000";
else (t1 = "1111") then temp <= r AND "1111111111";
    end if; 

if (temp = "1000000000") then 
    snd <= "1010";

    elsif (temp = "0100000000") then 
   snd <= "1001";

    elsif (temp = "0010000000") then
   snd <= "1000";

    elsif (temp = "0001000000") then 
    snd <= "0111"; 

    elsif (temp = "0000100000") then
    snd <= "0110";

    elsif (temp = "0000010000") then
    snd <= "0101";

    elsif (temp = "0000001000") then
    snd <= "0100";

    elsif (temp = "0000000100") then
    snd <= "0011";

    elsif (temp = "0000000010") then
    snd <= "0010";

    elsif (temp = "0000000001") then    
    snd <= "0001";

    else (temp = other ) then
    snd<= "1111";   
    end if; 


    end process;

    end count;
```

Comment: Hi, your code is riddled with other errors. There's a `begin` missing at line 16; you keep saying `else` instead of `elsif`; `else (temp = other )` means nothing - I think you just mean `else`. I fixed all those and then get some other error. I don't get the error you report. You need to fix all those other errors.

Comment: There's  a missing `begin` following the architecture declarative part (before the process statement). The first `else` should be `elsif`. The remaining `else`s should not have conditions or `then`. Fixing these the design specification analyzes, elaborates and simulates, demonstrating the string literals are all of the correct length. `r` is missing from the sensitivity list. The validity of your design hasn't been verified. Parentheses are not required around conditions, e.g. *if (condition) then*.